# Nginx reverse proxy для аутентификации Windows

Tags: nginx, proxy, active-directory

Я совсем недавно использую nginx и сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Есть сайт azuredevops.demo.lab. При входе на сайт требуется доменная аутентификация.
Я пытаюсь поставить между пользователем и Azure DevOps Server прокси nginx. В итоге у меня получилось получить форму ввода данных для аутентификации, однако после нажатия "Далее" форма появляется снова. Логи сервера говорят о следующем:

```
10.X.X.X - - [04/Jul/2022:16:06:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 1292 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.160 YaBrowser/22.5.3.684 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
10.X.X.X - - [04/Jul/2022:16:06:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 21772 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.160 YaBrowser/22.5.3.684 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
10.X.X.X - - [04/Jul/2022:16:06:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 341 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.160 YaBrowser/22.5.3.684 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
10.X.X.X - - [04/Jul/2022:16:06:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 1292 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.160 YaBrowser/22.5.3.684 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"
```

Вот конф файл nginx:

```
server {
        server_name azuredevops.demo.lab;
        listen 80;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen          443 ssl;
        server_name     azuredevops.demo.lab;

        # Logs
        access_log /var/log/nginx/azuredevops.demo.lab.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/azuredevops.demo.lab.log;

        # SSL
        include /etc/nginx/additional/certsXXX.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://10.Y.Y.Y;

                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

Прошу подскажите, каким именно образом необходимо проксировать такие запросы...

Comment: http запрос содержит заголовки и тело запроса. Вам нужно передать нужные для авторизации заголовки

Comment: Немного поискав в интернете нашел, что в запросе используется HTTP заголовком WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, NTLM. Можете подсказать как мне включить этот заголовок в конфигурацию proxy

Comment: Используйте proxy_set_header директиву